# Wifi drops out after being idle

Tags: wireless

I am running Ubuntu mate 20.04.  I have a consistent problem with my wifi.  If I use the wifi for any period (minutes or hours) I remain connected. I then leave the laptop and come back to it after 20 to 30 minutes. Then if I try to go to any web address it tells me that there is no internet.  I have tried using my phone (on wifi only) just before going back to the laptop and it connects with no problems, so I suspect that it may not be a router issue. The only solution that I have found is to disconnect and then reconnect. Which logs would be useful to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I have a similar issue with a wired connect 20.04.2 which I consistently reconnect successfully with the following command in terminal `sudo service network-manager restart`. There seems to be no rhyme nor reason for this behaviour. Next time it drops out, perhaps try that? As for logs, I haven't investigated that aspect but it doesn't happen on my 18.04 system.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; iwconfig; lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`